# git ls-remote without remote name

Tags: git

My repository is configured to have more than one remote. Then when I run `git ls-remote` for which remote is it showing the data ?

Earlier I thought it defaults to `origin` but upon changing remote name to `origin1` , it still  shows for it. Then moving on different branches in repository , it seems like choosing remotes from there. I am not sure. Not all branches are pushed to all remote repository.

Comment: From memory, I think it defaults to the remote of the upstream branch you're currently tracking on the branch that you have checked out. Try `git checkout -b TEMP` and then `git ls-remote`, this branch does not have an upstream branch yet, does it still show remote information through `git ls-remote` ?

Comment: No. It is not showing remote info. `fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen what if a local branch have 2 remote tracking branch ?

Comment: No, you cannot track two remote branches at the same time: if you track a 2nd remote, the 1st is no longer tracked.

Comment: From the source code `remote.c`,https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/remote.c, Line 666-675, we can see it's the remote specified by `branch.<name>.remote`. If not specified, `origin` is used if it exists.

Comment: @ElpieKay this is right answer. please post as answer

Comment: @MincongHuang I did not get you. I can see both remote tracking branch exists when I do `git branch -a`

Comment: Command `git branch -a` lists both local branches and remote branches. If you see the same branch appeared in both local and remote, it doesn't mean the local branch is tracked by the remote one. You should run `git branch -vv` to show the tracked information. For example, `master  c63e9c1 [origin/master] Add sth` means the local master is tracked to `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ElpieKay mentioned in the comments , (I am just posting it as answer)

From the source code [remote.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0df8e96566ddcae4adc4efc096944c064f60b8bd/remote.c#L666), **Line 666-675**, we can see it's the remote specified by `branch.<name>.remote`. If not specified, `origin` is used if it exists.